# How to set root of project for ESLint?

Tags: typescript, error-handling, next.js, eslint

For clarification, my project is built with Next.js and Typescript. I've been importing my functions this way: `import Component from "/components/Component/Component";`, where `/` refers to the `/src` folder (so I don't have to import all the functions with relative imports).

Next.js interprets it nicely and doesn't throw me an error, but ESLint does. For every line ESLint throws the error: `Cannot find module '/path/to/component' or its corresponding type declarations. ts(2307)`. It really infuriates me because the project looks like it has 48 errors while 80% of those errors are just from that one error.

Is there any way I can force ESLint to completely ignore the typescript error (TS2307)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not really common practice to start import from /. I would suggest adding baseUrl property to tsconfig.json if you don't have it already

```
"baseUrl": "./"
```

After that you can import your components like this

```
import Component from "components/Component/Component";
```